# inserting a string value ''Terminal$Attr1,Attr2,Attr3,Attr4,Attr5,Attr6,@Connector$Con1,Con2,Con3,Con4,@Wire$W1,W2,W3,W4,W5,' in a table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a query :

```
create table #mytable 
(table_id int IDENTITY(1,1), attribute_name varchar(20))

declare @strString varchar(500)
set @strString ='Terminal$Attr1,Attr2,Attr3,Attr4,Attr5,Attr6,@Connector$Con1,Con2,Con3,Con4,@Wire$W1,W2,W3,W4,W5,' 
Set @strString=REPLACE(REPLACE(@strString,'$',','),'@','')--Added

;WITH StrCTE(start, stop) AS

(
  SELECT  1, CHARINDEX(',' , @strString )
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  stop + 1, CHARINDEX(',' ,@strString  , stop + 1)
  FROM StrCTE
  WHERE stop > 0
) 
insert into #mytable 

SELECT   SUBSTRING(@strString , start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 4000 END) AS stringValue
FROM StrCTE
where SUBSTRING(@strString , start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 4000 END)<>''
--,
--case attribute_name
--when 'Terminal' then attribute_name like '%Attr%',
--when 'Connector' then attribute_name like '%Con%' ,
--when 'Wire' then attribute_name like '%W%'

select * from #mytable
```

the output which I am getting is :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohhUQ.png)

I need the output as : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1ZqI.png)

I have created family table too.. but unable to write the case and joins to get the result.

The query for family table is :

```
create table Family (family_id int identity,family_name varchar(300))

insert into Family values ('Terminal')

insert into Family values ('Connector')

insert into Family values ('Wire')

select * from Family
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### EDIT According to you comments:

```
DECLARE @strString VARCHAR(MAX) ='Terminal$Attr1,Attr2,Attr3,Attr4,Attr5,Attr6,@Connector$Con1,Con2,Con3,Con4,@Wire$W1,W2,W3,W4,W5,' ;

SET @strString='<family name="' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@strString,',','</x><x>'),'$','"><x>'),'@','</x></family><family name="') + '</x></family>';

DECLARE @xml XML= CAST(@strString AS XML);

WITH Families AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS FamilyID
          ,family.value('@name','varchar(max)') AS Family
          ,family.query('x') AS Children
    FROM @xml.nodes('family') AS The(family)
)
SELECT Families.FamilyID
      ,Families.Family
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ChildID
      ,Child.value('.','varchar(max)') AS ChildContent
INTO #tmpDataFamilies       
FROM Families
CROSS APPLY Children.nodes('/x[text()!=""]') AS One(Child);

INSERT INTO tblFamily(ID,FamilyName) --set your actual Family-Table with its actual column names here!
SELECT DISTINCT FamilyID,Family
FROM #tmpDataFamilies;

INSERT INTO tblChildren(ID,FamilyID,ChildName)--set your actual Family-Table with its actual column names here!
SELECT ChildID,FamilyID,ChildContent
FROM #tmpDataFamilies;

DROP TABLE #tmpDataFamilies;
```

#### previous

What about this?

```
DECLARE @strString VARCHAR(MAX) ='Terminal$Attr1,Attr2,Attr3,Attr4,Attr5,Attr6,@Connector$Con1,Con2,Con3,Con4,@Wire$W1,W2,W3,W4,W5,' ;

SET @strString='<family name="' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@strString,',','</x><x>'),'$','"><x>'),'@','</x></family><family name="') + '</x></family>';

SELECT @strString
SELECT CAST(@strString AS XML);
```

The result is an XML reflecting your families:

```
<family name="Terminal">
  <x>Attr1</x>
  <x>Attr2</x>
  <x>Attr3</x>
  <x>Attr4</x>
  <x>Attr5</x>
  <x>Attr6</x>
  <x />
</family>
<family name="Connector">
  <x>Con1</x>
  <x>Con2</x>
  <x>Con3</x>
  <x>Con4</x>
  <x />
</family>
<family name="Wire">
  <x>W1</x>
  <x>W2</x>
  <x>W3</x>
  <x>W4</x>
  <x>W5</x>
  <x />
</family>
```

With a query like this you'd get out the values:

```
DECLARE @xml XML= CAST(@strString AS XML);

SELECT family.value('@name','varchar(max)')
      ,children.value('.','varchar(max)')
FROM @xml.nodes('/family') AS The(family)
CROSS APPLY family.nodes('*') AS Many(children)
```

The result:

```
Terminal    Attr1
Terminal    Attr2
Terminal    Attr3
Terminal    Attr4
Terminal    Attr5
Terminal    Attr6
Terminal    
Connector   Con1
Connector   Con2
Connector   Con3
Connector   Con4
Connector   
Wire        W1
Wire        W2
Wire        W3
Wire        W4
Wire        W5
Wire
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this is not what extacly I am looking into.

Comment: @Rains Well: What are you looking to?

Comment: please look into the 2nd image in the questions asked.. Here I am unable to add the image.

Comment: @Rains, so you want the rows with generated IDs in two relational tables?

Comment: @Shungo :
Yes. I have created the family table. Family_Id will get referred to #mytable and will be providing me the output as desired.(like image 2).

Comment: @Rains, please see my EDIT section

Comment: @Shungo : Can you plz help me with my New Requirement. I am stuking in between and unable to proceed further.
Please follow the link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36284066/inserting-non-duplicate-data-from-parent-table-to-child-table-in-sql-server-2008