# Inserting Non duplicate data from parent table to child table in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables : A and B with same columns on both the table as :

```
Customer_Part_Number,
Lear_Part_Number,
Shipping_ID,
Customer_Name,
Effective_Date,
End_Date,Change_ID,
PO_Number,
PO_Price
```

I have successfully copied all the data to table B from table A
But my scenario  when the records of the columns :

```
TENANT_ID,          
CUSTOMER_PART_NUMBER,       
SHIPPING_ID,       
EFFECTIVE_DATE
```

are same in table A,I don't want it to get it inserted to table  B.
I have tried using the query :

```
INSERT INTO OSUSR_1SV_QAD_PO_DATA 
    (TENANT_ID,
     CUSTOMER_PART_NUMBER,
     LEAR_PART_NUMBER,
     SHIPPING_ID,
     CUSTOMER_NAME,
     PROGRAM_NAME,
     EFFECTIVE_DATE,
     END_DATE,
     CHANGE_ID,
     PO_NUMBER,
     PO_PRICE)
SELECT 
     TENANT_ID,
     CUSTOMER_PART_NUMBER,
     LEAR_PART_NUMBER,
     SHIPPING_ID,
     CUSTOMER_NAME,
     PROGRAM_NAME,
     EFFECTIVE_DATE,
     END_DATE,
     CHANGE_ID,
     PO_NUMBER,
     PO_PRICE 
FROM 
OSUSR_1SV_STAGING_FTP A
WHERE 
not exists
 ( SELECT TENANT_ID,
     CUSTOMER_PART_NUMBER,
     LEAR_PART_NUMBER,
     SHIPPING_ID,
     CUSTOMER_NAME,
     PROGRAM_NAME,
     EFFECTIVE_DATE,
     END_DATE,
     CHANGE_ID,
     PO_NUMBER,
     PO_PRICE
     FROM OSUSR_1SV_QAD_PO_DATA B
     WHERE
      A.TENANT_ID = B.TENANT_ID
       and A.CUSTOMER_PART_NUMBER = A.CUSTOMER_PART_NUMBER
       and A.SHIPPING_ID = B.SHIPPING_ID
       and  A.EFFECTIVE_DATE = B.EFFECTIVE_DATE )
```

Here, If the record of the columns TENANT_ID,CUSTOMER_PART_NUMBER,SHIPPING_ID,EFFECTIVE_DATE will be same, it wont be inserting the duplicate records.

Kindly help me out.

[image]

In the first Image there are duplicate data on table OSUSR_1SV_STAGING_FTP the basis of
TENANT_ID,
CUSTOMER_PART_NUMBER,
SHIPPING_ID,
EFFECTIVE_DATE

But I need to insert the data like Image 2 on table OSUSR_1SV_QAD_PO_DATA without duplication of 
TENANT_ID,
CUSTOMER_PART_NUMBER,
SHIPPING_ID,
EFFECTIVE_DATE
[image]

I have tried this query
MERGE OSUSR_1SV_QAD_PO_DATA  A
USING OSUSR_1SV_STAGING_FTP B
ON  (B.TENANT_ID = A.TENANT_ID and B.CUSTOMER_PART_NUMBER = A.CUSTOMER_PART_NUMBER
and B.SHIPPING_ID = A.SHIPPING_ID and  B.EFFECTIVE_DATE = A.EFFECTIVE_DATE )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
DELETE WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT MIN(ID)_
FROM OSUSR_1SV_STAGING_FTP
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_PART_NUMBER,SHIPPING_ID)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT   (TENANT_ID,CUSTOMER_PART_NUMBER,LEAR_PART_NUMBER,SHIPPING_ID,CUSTOMER_NAME,PROGRAM_NAME,EFFECTIVE_DATE,END_DATE,CHANGE_ID,PO_NUMBER,PO_PRICE)
VALUES(B.TENANT_ID,B.CUSTOMER_PART_NUMBER,B.LEAR_PART_NUMBER,B.SHIPPING_ID,
B.CUSTOMER_NAME,B.PROGRAM_NAME,B.EFFECTIVE_DATE,B.END_DATE,B.CHANGE_ID,B.PO_NUMBER,B.PO_PRICE);

Comment: Why doesn't your query work?

Answer (score 1):

Replace this part

```
not exists
( SELECT 1
 FROM OSUSR_1SV_QAD_PO_DATA B
 WHERE
  A.TENANT_ID = B.TENANT_ID
   --and A.CUSTOMER_PART_NUMBER = A.CUSTOMER_PART_NUMBER --you are Comparing same value here
   and A.CUSTOMER_PART_NUMBER = B.CUSTOMER_PART_NUMBER  
   and A.SHIPPING_ID = B.SHIPPING_ID
   and  CAST(A.EFFECTIVE_DATE AS DATE) = CAST(B.EFFECTIVE_DATE AS DATE) )
```

Comment: ITS NOT WORKING.. I AM GETTING AL THE RECORDS INCLUDING THE DUPLICATE RECORDS.

Comment: KINDLY SEE THE EDIT PART  I HAVE DONE.. aTTACHED THE IMAGE TOO
ITS NOT WORKING TOO

Comment: @Rains have you tried exact same as I demonstrated??.

Comment: @Rains I observe that duplicate records are not inserted, observe the effective date of each record is different. Still if you dont want those record then try updated my Ans

Comment: Thank you so much... just did slight changes in the query. Its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query :

```
        INSERT INTO OSUSR_1SV_QAD_PO_DATA 
(TENANT_ID,
 CUSTOMER_PART_NUMBER,
 LEAR_PART_NUMBER,
 SHIPPING_ID,
 CUSTOMER_NAME,
 PROGRAM_NAME,
 EFFECTIVE_DATE,
 END_DATE,
 CHANGE_ID,
 PO_NUMBER,
 PO_PRICE)

Select TENANT_ID,
 CUSTOMER_PART_NUMBER,
 LEAR_PART_NUMBER,
 SHIPPING_ID,
 CUSTOMER_NAME,
 PROGRAM_NAME,
 EFFECTIVE_DATE,
 END_DATE,
 CHANGE_ID,
 PO_NUMBER,
 PO_PRICE 
 from OSUSR_1SV_STAGING_FTP A

 INNER JOIN (select TENANT_ID,CUSTOMER_PART_NUMBER,SHIPPING_ID,EFFECTIVE_DATE from OSUSR_1SV_STAGING_FTP 
    group by TENANT_ID,CUSTOMER_PART_NUMBER,SHIPPING_ID,EFFECTIVE_DATE) as NoDuplicate ON A.TENANT_ID=NoDuplicate.TENANT_ID
```